# Call Web Service when contents change

Tags: smartsheet-api

We'd like to allow our users to make changes to our ERP (only very limited conditions) from within the smartsheet.  Is there a way to add a web service call based on changes to a cell?

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to do what you've described (provided, of course, that your ERP supports inbound web service calls to update data there).

If you're wanting to do this programmatically (i.e., by writing a script in Python or any other supported language), you can use the Smartsheet API to create one or more [webhooks](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/webhooksDescription) that will monitor Smartsheet for the type of changes you specify, and send your integration notifications when those events occur. Your integration would then *listen* for those inbound event notifications, and when they are received, it would programmatically issue the appropriate web service call(s) to update data in the ERP.

It's also worth mentioning that, depending on what ERP you're using, it may be possible for you to accomplish your goal without having to write any code. If you're interested in exploring the feasibility of that approach, I'd suggest you check out products like [Zapier](https://zapier.com), [Power Automate](https://flow.microsoft.com), etc. to see if they offer a connector for Smartsheet and your ERP. You may also want to check out the [Smartsheet Connectors and Integrations](https://www.smartsheet.com/marketplace/connectors-Integrations) page to see if there's a connector for your ERP listed there.